# Programming paradigm with heavy OO constraints

Tags: oop, paradigms

Hey. I remember reading somewhere about a programimng paradigm that has very tough restrictions about OO. It forbids nested ifs and elses entirely, avoid functions in the global namespace not associated with a class, and stuff like that. It's supposedly pretty famous. Does anyone know how it is called? Thanks.

I'll give an example. This is not supposed to be a totally serious paradigm - its just heavy restrictions to improve your "OO style". For example a FizzBuzz program you'll make an object that inherits from integer and has a method 'representMyself', and an object 'FizzBuzzNumbersRange' which holds an array of FizzBuzz numbers with a method 'representAll', or something. etc. etc.

Comment: I can't imagine a serious programming language that doesn't support nested `if` statements. Are you sure about that bit?

Comment: @Greg he said "paradigm" not language.  But it still sounds odd.

Comment: Are you sure you are not talking about Functional programming? which prefer recursive over nested structure or loop.

Comment: I remember seeing a Google Tech Talk about something that sounds like this, but I can't find it with a quick glance. I'm pretty sure it involved testing - it makes it easier to mock objects or something like that. I think they weren't actually advocating it, but just thinking out loud about the idea.

Comment: Have you tried Smalltalk? I don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're refering to [Object Calisthenics](http://www.google.com/search?q=object+calisthenics) which have the following rules:

1. Use one level of indentation per
   method
2. Don't use the else keyword
3. Wrap all primitives and strings
4. Use only one dot per line
5. Don't abbreviate
6. Keep all entities small
7. Don't use any classes with more than
   two instance variables
8. Use first class collections
9. Don't use any getters, setters or
   properties